# Django web project "blog.views has no attribute"

Tags: django

So I had the basic server running fine and then I created a page that said "Blog Home", but after I added another page that said "Blog About" now I'm getting this in my Cmd:

```
File "C:\Users\Christopher\Desktop\poo\blog\urls.py", line 6, in <module>
    path("about/", views.about, name="blog-about"),
AttributeError: module 'blog.views' has no attribute 'about'
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def home(response):
    return HttpResponse("<h1>Blog Home</h1>")

def about(response):
    return HttpResponse("<h1>Blog About</h1>")
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
path("", views.home, name="blog-home"),
path("about/", views.about, name="blog-about"),
```

I also had a very strange problem in that my code was not running at all yesterday, but then I started my computer today and ran the server and....magic! The server was working! Not sure if you can give me any suggestions as to why that was not working.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try restarting your server after adding the new view/url? Sometimes my server does not automatically restart after I change code

Comment: Yes, I did try restarting the server but it still does not work. I think there is some kind of other error and that is why I am asking here.

Comment: You might forgot to save the file `views.py` or your import references other views.py file with home view in it, share your project structure, if it's still relevant

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.